# Submiting a content as admin in Liferay (workflow)

Tags: workflow, liferay

I'm create a simple site (intranet) where I'm a admin, but when submiting a content, this stay as: pendent. Why? I'm the administrator of Liferay Portal.

I don't have experience with Liferay, but it's so complicated this workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to approve the content as some user that has appropriate role in the document's workflow.

You can do it in control-panel -> my workflow tasks.

First assign the task to you and then approve the content.

Comment: alternatively, as we don't know what the setup for users is, just disable workflow for web content - as it must have been manually enabled.

Comment: @OlafKock with 6.0.6 and 6.1.0 it's enabled by default AFAIK

Comment: ouch - I'm never running with the sevencogs demo content, that's why I don't see it. In this case, I add to the tip to start with a blank installation and remove sevencogs-hook before the first start.